# Foreach looping data in a array to check against items in another array

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0

I've tried many variations but I am unable to pass the value from one `foreach` to another `foreach` loop. I am trying to parse through event logs for login logout info and then create a CSV file for each computer. The script works for a single file but once I use the `foreach` loops I get no responses in my CSV file. Including the script below. The `$name3` variable does not make it to the last  `foreach` statement.

How do I pass the value of `$name3` to the nested `foreach` loop?

```
$userlist = Import-Csv -Path "W:\admin\logs\computers.log" 

foreach ($xcomputer in $userlist) {
  $name3 = $xcomputer."test"

  $arrtest = Import-Csv -Path "W:\admin\logs\log_times.log" -Delimiter " " | 
             Sort-Object -Property date
  $s = $name3 + ".csv"
  $outfile = "W:\admin\logs\reports\$s"

  Write-Output "action,datetime,user" | Out-File $outfile
  foreach ($Users1 in $arrtest) {
    if ($name3 -eq $users1.computer) {
      $action1 = $Users1.action
      $date1 = $Users1.date
      $time1 = $Users1.time
      $user1 = $Users1.user
      $datetime = $date1 + " " + $time1 
      Write-Output "$action1,$datetime,$user1" | Out-File $outfile -Append
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. Please provide evidence.

Comment: I figured out the way to carry the value over using $xcomputer.test instead of assigning that to a variable. Now I have another issue. My If statement is always true even when the data is different. Here is my statement  If ($xcomputer.test -and $zcomputer) {Do this} same results if I use -eq The data is text names of computers

Answer (score 0):

I switched my Input-CSV's before the foreach loops and everything is working fine